# $_FILES not returning any value

Tags: php, html

I am trying to upload a file but the `$_FILES` variable is not returning any value from the form.
The top code is of the HTML form which is accepting the file and the bottom one is of the file to which the form is redirecting.

When I am trying to print the json encoded value of `$_FILES` is coming out to be empty.

HTML code:

```
<form id='text' action ='http://getlegal.in/registration-details/' method = 'POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='12412412' /> 
    <label for='file'>Profile Pic :</label>

    <input type='file' name='file' id='file' required='required'><br>

    <Input type='submit' name='option' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
$allowedExts = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
//echo "yaba daba doo ";
//echo json_encode($temp);
echo json_encode($_FILES);
echo $_FILES['file']['name'];
die();
if (
$_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"
|| $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg"
|| $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"
|| $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png"
|| $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"
&&($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 500000000 )
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) 
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
    {
            echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
            echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) 
        {
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
        else 
        {
                 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                 "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                 echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            }
    }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file<br>";
  echo "Please uplaoad a valid file. Chech the file type(jpg, png, jpeg) and the size (500kb)";


  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  echo $_FILES["file"]["size"];
  die ();
```

Comment: The posted code block doesn't contain any valid php code since there is no php open tag anywhere.

Comment: I have just pasted the relevant code..not the entire one..Its within tags.. -_-

Comment: @SuperDJ..but the solution to that question is Method..my method is already post..

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
$out = array_values($FILES);
json_encode($out);
```